# How to remove white border of buttons with FlatStyle = Standard

Tags: c#, winforms, button

We have created one custom button with FlatStyle = Standard.
But now if I try to change the backcolor of the button a white border is showing around the button.

But if the button FlatStyle = Flat, there is no white border is showing.

Can some one give a suggestion to remove the white border.

Please find the image below.Here these are two buttons,with BackColor = Blue, but white border is there around these two buttons.

[image]

Comment: We too were struggling to get the standard button control to look like we wanted. We ended up creating our own button control deriving from Control:

    class MyButton : Control
    {
    ...

This way we have full control over the behavior and appearance.
Let me know if more information is wanted.

Comment: @JohnSaps: Yes..How you customized the custom button. For me now I am trying to use FlatStyle = flat and try to customize it sothat it will look like some button. Can you pls show how you have customized your button

Comment: We created our own button, which is a bit more work than you probably want to put into this. When you create it from scratch there are no such properties like FlatStyle etc. You define all this yourself.

Comment: Cody Gray has some good points why not create the button yourself, unless you really know what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The white border is not actually white, it is a light-gray color. And it is part of the `FlatStyle.Standard` drawing theme. The border around the button is what makes it 3D, like a push button.

If you don't want that, then you don't want `FlatStyle.Standard`. And you probably don't want this style anyway, since it does not respect the system theme. `FlatStyle.System` does, and is almost always a better choice. Of course, you lose the built-in support for images, meaning you'll have to write code to draw the image yourself.

Alternatively, you can just set `FlatStyle.Flat`. As you've seen, that removes the border and makes a flat button. The only problem with this is that it gives you an unusable interface, a la iOS 7—nobody knows which widgets are clickable anymore. The whole point of a button control is that it offers visual affordance. Even the poor man's button (the hyperlink control) has an underline that makes it look clickable. A flat button has nothing to distinguish it from an ornamental image.

Of course, you *can* set `FlatStyle.Flat` and draw whatever border manually. That gives you total control. But it also means that *you* have to have the design skills to make something that looks good. If you're like most programmers, that's not likely. Since you're going to have to custom-draw anyway, you might as well set `FlatStyle.System` and draw the image. It's always better to let the operating system do the heavy lifting for you. Not only will that produce better-looking results, but it will give you something that the user is already familiar with and accustomed to using. As a special bonus, your app's widgets automatically update to the snazzy new themes used by new versions of the operating system.

Here is some sample code to get you started on adding images to buttons with the `FlatStyle.System` style: [Images on XP-Style Buttons](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6115/Images-on-XP-Style-Buttons). It was written way back when, about Windows XP, but as I mentioned, the whole point of this style is that it lets the system draw the button, meaning that when you run the code, you'll get the nice Aero buttons or whatever Windows 9 uses.

Comment: It's funny that nowadays flat buttons are common in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that unless you set `FlatStyle` to `Flat` and `FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0`. Another possibility is to [handle custom painting](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/164861/How-to-remove-border-of-a-Standard-Button-in-Win-f).

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pevent);
        using (Pen p = new Pen(BackColor, 5))
        {
            p.Alignment = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Inset;
            pevent.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, ClientRectangle);
        }
    }
}
```